# Pre-configuração de funções

Tags: php

Olá, eu tenho um BOT de facebook e eu criei uma função chamada enviaMSG(); e dentro dela paço 2 parâmetros, o id do facebook do usuário e a mensagem a enviar mas em todo o código eu uso bastantes vezes esta função e eu as vezes esqueço de passar o id do facebook, tem como já definir no inicio o id do facebook?

Comment: Você pode definir o valor do parâmetro como padrão na definição da função.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de algumas maneiras diferentes.

[DEFINIR UMA CONSTANTE](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.define.php) ou variável e depois chamar ela no seu código. Ex.:

```
<?php
define("ID_FACEBOOK","SEU_ID_AQUI");
...
enviaMSG(ID_FACEBOOK,"Você está procurando por um hotel?");
?>
```

Criar uma CLASS para suas funções relacionadas e depois poder utilizar os dados salvos dentro dela. Ex.:

```
<?php
class uteisFacebook{
    public $id_facebook="";

    public function enviaMSG($msg){
        ... sua função aqui, mas quando for chamar o ID use: $this->id_facebook
    }
}
?>
```

Depois você configura a classe no seu código, se você tiver um arquivo de configuração que é chamado em todas as páginas você pode fazer isso dentro dele, assim não precisa sempre reconfigurar.

```
<?php
// Inclua o arquivo da classe:
include("uteisFacebook.php");
// Chame a classe e defina suas variáveis
$facebook=new uteisFacebook();
$facebook->id_facebook="defina_o_id_aqui";
?>
```

E Finalmente para chamar a função:

```
<?php
$facebook->enviaMSG("Você tem um tempinho para falar do nosso senhor e criador, Markinho da galera?");
?>
```

Bom, isso são apenas exemplos para te ajudar a chegar onde quer, mas no caso de usar class recomendo dar uma pesquisada melhor sobre [como construir uma classe](https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2014/08/criar-classes-em-php/).